# In laravel using ajax call and get the document.execCommand("copy") but its not working

Tags: ajax, laravel

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:apprul,
    success:function(request){
        var copy = $('.class');
        Clipboard(copy);
     },
     error: function (request, error)
     {
        alert('Your Login session is expiry please log in and try again');
        window.location.href = apprul;
      }
});
```

Comment: Clipboard(copy) function call for document.execCommand("copy").

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
   type:'GET',
   url:apprul,
   async: false, 
   success:function(request){
     var copy = $('.class');
     Clipboard(copy);
   },
   error: function (request, error)
   {
     alert('Your Login session is expiry please log in and try again');
     window.location.href = apprul;
    }
  });
```